# Accessing PHP session variable from different paths

Tags: php, session

I am facing a very weird problem in PHP sessions, here are the facts:

**Creating a session variable code - mydomain/a/b/c/create_session.php**

```
<?
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['test'] = "Hello World";
?>
```

**Reading the session variable read mydomain/a/b/c/read_session.php**

```
<?
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION['test'];
?>
```

**The Problem**

When I access the read_session.php code from within the same URL it works fine.
But when I'm trying to read the session variable from a different path, it doesn't work.

**Examples**

mydomain/a/b/c/read_session.php - works!

mydomain/a/b/read_session.php - works!

mydomain/a/read_session.php - works!

mydomain/read_session.php - **doesn't works!**

mydomain/d/read_session.php - **doesn't works!**

Comment: Which directory are you starting the session (=setting the cookie) in? My memory is hazy on the issue, but I 
*think* if you don't specify a path, the cookie will be valid only for that path and subdirectories

Comment: Have you checked what path your session cookie is actually valid for? (Try Firefox + the Web Developer addon) - I duplicated what you described on my localhost and there was no problem. The session cookie was valid for the whole domain. (PHP 5.3, default settings.)

Comment: I am using
ini_set('session.cookie_path', '/');

Comment: Hi Atli,  "/a" though I'm using the ini_set('session.cookie_path','/') Maybe I should try using the 4th argument is setcookie() to '/' too..

Answer (score 2):

You could try using [`session_set_cookie_params`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-cookie-params.php), in case you have a configuration setting muddling things up somewhere:

```
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/');
session_start();
```

You can configure cookies to be usable only on certain paths on the domain. It's possible that that has happened here.  NB that if this is the issue, the best way to fix it is by changing the value in `php.ini`:

```
session.cookie_path = "/"
```

Comment: I've added this line
session_set_cookie_params(0, '/');
before the session_start(); 
In the same way you mentioned, but unfortunately it didn't help.
The same problem occurs.

Answer (score 1):

That couldn't be the problem.

Domains need to be exaclty the same (cookie policy), that means http://www.domain is not the same as http://domain

Comment: Check out the session id cookie in the browser and compare the cookie paths.

Answer (score 0):

As Briedis says, you might not be using the same domains. They have be the same.

Make sure you check your [session.cookie_paths](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-path). It is possible your configuration settings are setting the cookie's path to "/a". In that case, the functionality you describe would occur, because there would be a path mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies (and thus cookies for session IDs) can be bound to certain domains and paths. The default configuration of PHP’s session ID cookies is to bound the cookies to the current domain ([*session.cookie_domain*](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-domain)) and the path `/` ([*session.cookie_path*](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-path)).

Maybe your session configuration differs from the default configuration insofar as the cookie’s path is set to `/a` so that the cookie on only valid in `/a` as well as those paths where `/a` is a proper path prefix (i.e. `/a/…`).

Try to change the cookie path to `/`:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_path', '/');
```

Comment: Well the path is set to '/' as I can see in view cookies extension of Firefox, but I've tried this too right now and it didn't help either :(

Comment: I can see in the Cookie info extension that the path is set to '/a' even though I am using ini_set('session.cookie_path', '/') at the beginning of the script.

Comment: @Amir E. Habib: Hm, that’s weird. Try `session_set_cookie_params` instead: `$old = session_get_cookie_params(); session_set_cookie_params($old['lifetime'], '/');`.