# PHP: Session vaiables not accessible in sub-directory

Tags: php, session-variables, subdirectory

I have encountered a strange problem.  I have a password protected site with most of my files in the main directory.  All the files are inaccessible before login but upon setting a session variable become accessible.  I use other session variables as well, all of which are accessible to these files.

However, for convenience I dumped a bunch of files related to one topic into a sub-directory.  However, I've discovered that files in this sub-directory do not seem to have access to the session variables.

php

```
login.php
$_SESSION['username'] = "Bob"; //sets session variable.

subdir/file.php
echo $_SESSION['username']; //echoes nothing.
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
if (!isset($username)) {
echo "var not set"; //echoes out
}
```

Has anyone encountered this issue before?  What could it be?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Silly question, but have you called session_start() in the subdir/file.php ?

Comment: Did you check this one?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4957523/accessing-php-session-variable-from-different-paths

Comment: You called it!  Always the obvious things one forgets.  Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you started the session in those pages : `session_start();`

You have to start the session in pages were you assign values to session as well as on the pages where you use seesion values.

Answer (score 1):

You should add session_start() before you can call a session variable so that your $_SESSION['username'] will not be undefined or empty.

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to start session with this

```
session_start();
```

and then until the session ends you can get those variables that are stored in session can be used in your all directories and subdirectories

Answer (score 0):

Type

```
 Session_start();
```

at beggining of the page...
And echo the variable..

```
echo $<variable_name>;
```

You can see the value